# wp_mail 200 response but no mail sent

Tags: ajax, email, wp-mail

I'm trying to send email from WP using ajax to validate the form and wp_mail to send the mail.

The form is a basic form with id names on the fields

The js validtion looks like this

```
    $(function(){
      $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(verfiyFields()) {
          requestData = {
            'action' : 'myajax-submit',
            'firstName' : $("#name").val(), 
            'email' : $("#email").val(), 

          }
          $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData).done(function(result){        
            //result = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
            if(result ==  'success'){
              console.log('email0-sent')
            }
          });
        }
      });
    })

    function verfiyFields() {
      var flag = true;

      var name =        $('#name');
      var email =       $('#email');

      if(name.val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ){
        name.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter name, first space last</p>');
        errorMessage($('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      if(!IsEmail(email.val())){
        email.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter valid email address</p>');
        errorMessage($('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      return flag;
    }
```

I'm using grunt to concate and minify the js so I'm enqueue the js script which includes the validation in the functions.php like this.

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

    function add_my_script() {
        wp_register_script('scripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/compiled/main.min.js', array('jquery'),1 ,true);

        wp_enqueue_script('scripts');

        wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
    }
```

and the myajax_submit function like this.

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

    function myajax_submit() {
        // get the submitted parameters

        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['firstName']);
        $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n"; //Enables HTML ContentType. Remove it for Plain Text Messages
        //$to = TRAINING_EMAIL;
        $to = 'me@mysite.co.uk';

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        // generate the response
        $response = json_encode( array( 'success') );

        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;

        // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
        exit;
    }
```

I'm using a correct email address in the $to variable.

If I test on a live server the valdation works.

In Chromes Network tab I can see the admin-ajax.php run and the header tab on the right shows a Status code of 200 OK

Does this mean the mail should have been sent - I don't get any email